# How to iterate over a sequence in systemd?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, systemd

We're migrating from ubuntu 14 to ubuntu 16.

I have the following upstart task:

```
description "Start multiple Resque workers."
start on runlevel [2345]
task
env NUM_WORKERS=4
script
  for i in `seq 1 $NUM_WORKERS`
  do
    start resque-work-app ID=$i
  done
end script
```

As you can see, I have 4 workers that I'm starting. There is an upstart script then that starts each one of these workers:

```
description "Resque work app"
respawn
respawn limit 5 30
instance $ID
pre-start script
  test -e /home/opera/bounties || { stop; exit 0; }
end script
exec sudo -u opera sh -c "<DO THE WORK>"
```

How do I do something similar in systemd? I'm particularly interested in how to iterate over a sequence of 4, and start a worker for each - this way, I'd have a cluster of 4 workers.

Answer (score 1):

`systemd` doesn't have an iteration syntax, but it still has features to help solve this problem. The related concepts that `systemd` provides are:

- Target Units, which allow you to treat a related group of services as a single service.
- Template Units, which allow you to easily launch new copies of an app based on a variable like an ID.

With systemd, you could run a one-time bash loop as part of setting up the service that would enable the desired number of workers:

```
for i in `seq 1 4`; { systemctl enable resque-work-app@1; }
```

That presumes you have a `resque-work-app@.service` file that includes something like:

```
 [Install]
 WantedBy=resque-work-app.target
```

And that you have have a `resque-work-app.target` that contains something like:

```
[Unit]                                                                                                                                                                  
Description=Resque Work App                                                                                                                                         

[Install]                                                                                                                                                               
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### See Also

- [How to create a virtual systemd service to stop/start several instances together?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283714/how-to-create-a-virtual-systemd-service-to-stop-start-several-instances-together)
- [man systemd.target](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html)
- [man systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)
- [About Instances and Template Units](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/instances.html)